# Does Android provide a way to access the user's address list?

Tags: android

I am designing an Android app (not coding it) and I want the user to be able to select a contact from the address list. I am pretty sure this can be done, but I would like to be certain, and also having some more details regarding the UI. Does the OS provide a system wide dialog for this, similar to the file upload screen? If so, can you provide a link with more info or screenshots?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you will need to add permissions on the manifest, but overall, the answer is yes.

It's done via "contacts-provider". You can check an example in the following link.

http://developer.android.com/training/contacts-provider/retrieve-names.html